# Search Lines for a chat_id, then the corresponding row

Tags: python

I am saving a database of users with a time key in the corresponding row.

I need to be able to search the file for the id, then if found check the corresponding row to compare to another value. Not sure how to read rows from a file in python.

example of my keys.txt file is

```
('5492828044', 1659360099957.5688)
('54654', 1657397829695.41)
('875186', 1659385033770.0159)
('654564', 1656879437623.957)
('4564564', 1657397840229.474)
```

The code I was previously using just searched for the id and I had to manually add and remove them.

```
keys = open('keys.txt', 'r')
    flag = 0
    index = 0
    for line in keys:
        index += 1
        if str(id) in line:
            flag = 1
            break
    if flag == 0:
```

Not sure how to look for a specific id then compare the next row with a current value I have stored.

Comment: Do the file contents always look like this `('5492828044', 1659360099957.5688)`? Are there any other different characters, or tuples with different sizes inside it? Edit the answer and give us an insight on how the file contents are displayed.

Comment: I'd recommend adding an example from the 'keys.txt' file so we understand the structure we're working with. At least 8-10 lines of sample data.

Comment: Also, in this line `str(id)` you're using the variable `id`. Where is `id` defined on your script? Did you post your entire script, or just a piece of it?

Comment: Be careful that, by default, `id` is a global function to get the memory address of each variable. So if you're going to use this later on, use another variable name for `id`, such as `_id`.

Comment: The data I showed in the first code box is how all the data is displayed in keys.txt